# How to debug Subclipse / SvnKit credentials issue?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, svnkit

I'm trying to get svnkit to work with subclipse. I'm on Windows 7, 64 bit, with Eclipse Indigo, JDK 1.6.

I installed subclipse 1.6.18 and svnkit 1.3.5.7406.

I add an svn repository location:

svn+ssh://my.server.com/srv/svn/repos

and tried to connect. Svnkit properly pops up a dialog asking for ssh credentials. I fill in the username, select "Use private key authentication", browse to my keyfile, enter a passphrase, and click "Save information". Hit ok.

The dialog closes and reopens with "Use password authentication" checked. No error messages, no other indication of what the problem might be.

How do I debug this?

---

Update: when I copied over the .keyring file from my old installation of Eclipse, which had successfully connected to the repo in the past, everything worked. Doesn't solve the problem for the future, though. My best guess is that svnkit can't write to the keyring in Indigo.

Comment: Have a look at DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager. It will be interesting from where acknowledgeAuthentication() will be called with accepted = false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem. The issue was that I was using the wrong private key file.

For future readers of this question, the way to debug the issue is to turn on Svnkit logging: http://wiki.svnkit.com/Troubleshooting#SVNKit_is_used_as_Eclipse_plugin_.28works_for_Subclipse_extension_as_well.29. The ".options" file is actually embedded in the svnkit jar.

The main problem is that when svnkit gets the wrong credentials, it doesn't bother to give you any error message. It just shows the dialog again. That little design problem cost me several hours of debugging yesterday.

Comment: Using this info I found the cause for why it didn't work for me: SVNKit doesn't like the puttygen private key format, but works fine after converting to OpenSSH format (via puttygen). Just found a more detailed answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36284242